# How does Boost Serialization Versioning work?

Tags: serialization, boost, version, versioning, boost-serialization

Can someone explain to me how the versioning in Boost Serialization works. The archive version is always 10 and the class version 0. I thought that the version is automatically incremented when the archive is different then the last version. Do I have to define the version number by myself if I changed something?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE boost_serialization>
<boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="10">
    <EventSet class_id="0" tracking_level="0" version="0">
        <Size>1</Size>
        <Event>
        ...
        </Event>
    </EventSet>
</boost_serialization>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you think that would work. However, the tutorial in [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#versioning) seems pretty clear.

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks again. I think, I misunderstood it, but now It's clearer to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not described in Boost documentation but the line `boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="10"` corresponds to the version of Boost.Archive library, it sometimes changes when new version of Boost becomes available.

As documentation explains, the line `EventSet class_id="0" tracking_level="0" version="0"` corresponds to the class version. You can change it in your code with a macro 'BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(EventSet, 1)'.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer by Michael, the boost archive version depends on your boost version and is bumped whenever some meaningful changes to the output format are made. There is a comment explaining these versions in `src/basic_archive.cpp` of the boost serialization git at https://github.com/boostorg/serialization/blob/develop/src/basic_archive.cpp At the time of writing this reads:

```
// this should change if the capabilities are added to the library
// such that archives can be created which can't be read by previous
// versions of this library
// 1 - initial version
// 2 - made address tracking optional
// 3 - numerous changes - can't guarantee compatibility with previous versions
// 4 - Boost 1.34
//     added item_version to properly support versioning for collections 
// 5 - Boost 1.36
//     changed serialization of collections: adding version even for primitive
//     types caused backwards compatibility breaking change in 1.35
// 6 - Boost 1.41 17 Nov 2009
//     serializing collection sizes as std::size_t
// 7   Boost 1.42 2 Feb 2010
//     error - changed binary version to 16 bits w/o changing library version #
//     That is - binary archives are recorded with #6 even though they are
//     different from the previous versions.  This means that binary archives
//     created with versions 1.42 and 1.43 will have to be fixed with a special
//     program which fixes the library version # in the header
//     Boost 1.43 6 May 2010
//     no change
// 8 - Boost 1.44
//     separated version_type into library_version_type and class_version_type
//     changed version_type to be stored as 8 bits.
// 10- fixed base64 output/input.
// 11- not changes
// 12- improved serialization of collections
// 13- simplified visibility, removed Borland, removed pfto
// 14- improved visibility, refactor map/set
// 15- corrections to optional and collection loading
// 16- eliminated dependency on <codecvt> which is buggy in some libraries
//     and now officially deprecated in the standard
// 17- Boost 1.68 August 2018
// 18- addressed undefined behavior in archive constructors.
//     init() called from base wrote archive header before archive
//     was fully constructed.
```